# If $f_n\rightarrow f$ in $L^p$-norm, $1\leq p<\infty$, then $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}m(\{x\in\mathbb{R}^d:|f_n(x)-f(x)|>\varepsilon\})=0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Let $1\leq p<\infty.$ Let $(f_n)_n$ be a sequence in $L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ that converges to some $f\in L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, in $L^p$-norm. Prove that for every $\varepsilon>0$ we have
>   $$l=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}m\left(\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^d:|f_n(x)-f(x)|>\varepsilon\right\}\right)=0,$$
>   where $m(E)$ denotes the Lebesgue measure of $E.$

My work so far:

Suppose for a contradiction that $l>0.$ Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given, and let $E_n=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^d:|f_n(x)-f(x)|>\varepsilon\right\}$. Since $f_n\rightarrow f$, in $L^p$-norm, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\|f_n-f\|_{p}<\varepsilon\cdot m(E_N)^{1/p}$ for all $n>N,$ where $N$ is such that $m(E_N)>0,$ can be chosen since $l>0$. Then 
$$\left(\int_{E_N}\varepsilon^{p}\,dx\right)^{1/p}=\varepsilon\cdot m(E_N)^{1/p}<\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|f_n(x)-f(x)|^p\,dx\right)^{1/p}=\|f_n-f\|_p,$$
which is a contradiction, so we must have $l=0.$

---

Is my reasoning above correct? Any comments are very welcomed, be it about the correctness or the style of the proof, or both.

Thank you for your time, and appreciate any feedback.

Comment: The fact that such $N$ exists is not that clear to me. You should give more arguments about this.

Comment: I don't understand why $\|f-f_n\|\leq \varepsilon m(E_N)$. Btw, if it would be true, roughly speaking your $\varepsilon $ would depend on $N$ which is not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly, it's just Markov inequality !
$$m\{|f_n-f|>\varepsilon \}\leq \frac{1}{\varepsilon ^p}\int|f_n-f|^p\to 0,$$

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, was my approach correc?

Comment: I answered in the comment of your question. @GabyAlfonso

Comment: @stressedout: Let $E=\{|f_n-f|>\varepsilon \}$, then $\varepsilon \boldsymbol 1_E\leq |f_n-f|\boldsymbol 1_E\leq |f_n-f|$. Therefore $\varepsilon ^p\boldsymbol 1_{E}\leq |f_n-f|^p.$ Integrate both side and you'll get your result ;)

Comment: Yup. I immediately realized that the proof is simple and proved it by myself. Thank you.